# subsets in the cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C,D$ be sets. Consider $A\times B$ and $X\subseteq A\times B$. Is it true that $X$ has the form $A'\times B'$ where $A'\subseteq A$ and $B'\subseteq B$ ?
At the same time is it true that $(A\times B)\cup (C\times D)=(A\cup C)\times (B\cup D)$?

For me are both false but I don't know how to prove them.
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prove the first statement is false with a counter-example.  Consider the diagonal line in $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R$.  It is not of the form $A'\times B'$ because every point is of the form $(x,x)$.

The second is also false.  Consider $A=[0,1]$, $B=[1,2]$ and $C=B$ and $D=A$.  Then the LHS is a union of two squares of side length $1$ while the RHS is a square of side length $2$.

Answer (score 2):

For the first, let $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{a,b\}, X=\{(1,a),(2,b)\}$  For the second, note that the pairs on the left have a first element that might come from $B$ while the pairs on the right have a first element that might come from $C$.  Maybe, as in my first example, they are different things.